Node/ExpressJs fail to handle 1000 requests at the same time
I have 2 expressjs servers:
Server A:
const express = require('express')
const axios = require('axios');
const app = express()
const port = 3000

function deepSleep (duration) {
  const start = new Date().getTime();
  while (true) {
    const current = new Date().getTime();
    if (current - start > duration) break;
  }
}

app.get('/:id', async (req, res) => {
  deepSleep(30); // just for better observation when testing this behavior
  await axios.get('http://localhost:3001/' + req.params.id);  // call to B
  res.send('Hello World!');
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})

Server B:
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3001

app.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
  console.log(new Date().getTime());
  console.log(req.params);
  res.sendStatus(200);
})

const server = app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})

The problem is, when I send 1000 requests to server A, instead of calling server B right away for each request, it just keeps processing them all in a row. Then, it finally calls server B for all 1000 requests at once! That's not what I expected.
My expectation: request 1 -> call server B -> request 2 -> call server B
Reality: request 1 -> request 2 -> ... -> request 1000 -> call server B (1) -> call server B (2) -> ... -> call server B (1000)
This is making server B super overloaded and causing each request to take way longer.
I'm thinking maybe it has something to do with the Node event loop. Is there anything I'm missing here? I'd expect Node to handle these requests asynchronously and efficiently, but this isn't behaving like that.
Edit 1: Let set aside the deepSleep blocking the event loop. What makes me surprise is that I always thought when encountering a promise axios.get(...), it will trigger the promise immediately and print the connection on the serverB terminal. But that's not the case, the serverA waits to process for 1000 requests before executing server B promises.
Edit 2:
Caller site:
const axios = require('axios');

for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i+= 1) {
  axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/${i}`);
}


Rename deepSleep to furiousBusyLoop, because that's what it is.  There is nothing sleepy about repeatedly calling new Date().getTime();    In fact, you should probably remove that function entirely.  It does no good and probably only confuses you further.  It may even be the sole cause of your current confusion.

Javascript in nodejs (if you're not explicitly invoking WorkerThreads) runs your Javascript single threaded.
So, when you create a busy loop like your deepSleep() function, then you're tying up that ONE thread in a busy loop and essentially blocking the entire event loop.  So, your server can do nothing while you're looping.
If you change serverA to something like this:
const express = require('express')
const axios = require('axios');
const app = express()
const port = 3000

function deepSleep (duration) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(resolve, duration);
  });
}

app.get('/:id', async (req, res) => {
  await deepSleep(30); // just for better observation when testing this behavior
  await axios.get('http://localhost:3001/' + req.params.id);  // call to B
  res.send('Hello World!');
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})

Which is not a busy loop, but instead awaits a promise, then you won't be blocking the event loop with a busy loop.

Since it appears you are missing a fundamental architectural element of the http server in nodejs, let me repeat.  Nodejs does not run each incoming request in its own thread.  By default, they all run in the same thread.  You should be using non-blocking I/O, not blocking I/O and that non-blocking I/O will not block the event loop.
If you have CPU-intensive code that needs to be part of a request handler (such as cryptographic operations or heavy compression or image processing), then you can move that specific code to a thread pool using WorkerThreads or to child processes so that it doesn't block the event loop.  That is how you architect request handlers in nodejs.
If you want every incoming request in it's own thread, then you are probably better off picking a different environment that has that as a fundamental part of its architecture (as do some Java frameworks), but that also comes with the added chore of handling data synchronization properly so you don't get race conditions when multiple threads are trying to access the same data.

I'm thinking maybe it has something to do with the Node event loop.

Yes, your deepSleep() function blocks the entire event loop for everything running in that nodejs process.

I'd expect Node to handle these requests asynchronously and efficiently, but this isn't behaving like that.

It will if you use proper asynchronous coding practices and don't block the event loop with a busy loop.

Let set aside the deepSleep blocking the event loop. What makes me surprise is that I always thought when encountering a promise axios.get(...), it will trigger the promise immediately and print the connection on the serverB terminal. But that's not the case, the serverA waits to process for 1000 requests before executing server B promises.

@DuyPhan - All 1000 incoming requests arrive BEFORE any request gets to axios.get() (because of the deepSleep() blocking) and before any incoming requests to serverB arrive also so all 1000 incoming requests get started first.  It's just FIFO ordering in the event loop networking queue.

What a fantastic journey you have been through! 25 years of development experience and still helping the world! Hats off! Your great comment led me to your profile. It would be a matter of pride for me to connect with you, at least over LinkedIn.
